# Prove $x^n+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ iff $n=2^k$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Unfortunately, I cannot find any information on or anything similar to this particular question. Might be quite new.

In all honesty, I don't know how to tackle either side of this question. By induction? By contradiction?

The theorems I just learned are Eisenstein"s criterion and reduction by modulo $n$ but nothing else. And both do not seem to help in any explicit way.

Does anyone have ideas on how to solve this problem at all? Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. If $n$ is divisible by an odd positive integer $d$, then $x^n+1$ is divisible by $x^{n/d}+1$.
2. If $f(x) = x^{2^k}+1$, apply Eisenstein to $f(x+1)$.

Comment: Of course if $n$ is odd, then $x=-1$ is a solution which is easier to notice.