# factoring, finding Rupture and Splitting fields over $Z3$ and complex of polynomial $x^8-1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, factoring

For polynomial $x^8-1$ I'm tasked to do $3$ things:

1) factor polynomial into irreducible polynomials over integer field with polynomials.

2) find all rupture and splitting fields over complex numbers.

3) find a splitting field over $\mathbb Z_3$, how many elements does it have?

For the **1st** task there is a hint: Use substitution and Eisenstein's criteria to proof some polynomials of the form $x^n+1$ are irreducible over integer field with polynomials.

$1)$
I'm kinda puzzled by the hint since I went with distribution: $$x^8-1=(x^4-1)(x^4+1)=(x^2-1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1)=(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1).$$ It's easy to see (for example from derivative) what minimum of polynomials $(x^2+1)$ and $(x^4+1)$ making positive functions over real(but that requires continuity). Which would make these irreducible as the other two are already of degree $1$.

$2)$ Rupture fields are $\mathbb Q(1)= \mathbb Q,\mathbb Q(-1)=\mathbb Q, \mathbb Q(e^{πi})$ and $\mathbb Q(e^{πi/2})$ for polynomials $(x-1)$, $(x+1)$, $(x^2+1)$ and $(x^4+1)$ respectively. Making the splitting field same as the last rupture field $\mathbb Q(e^{πi/2})$.

$3)$ I believe the splitting field to be $\mathbb Z_3(2^{\frac{1}{4}})$ for that sufficises all the polynomials $(x+2)(x+1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1)$, where $2^\frac{1}{2}$ you get as $2^\frac{1}{4}*2^\frac{1}{4}$. The number of elements is $3+3*2+3*2+3*2=21.$

Can you check whether my assumptions are correct/give me an explanation on the hunt for $1)$?

Thanks for your time

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rupture_field (the definition our courses uses goes: Let T be a field and f from T[x] a polynomial of degree >0. Rupture field of polynomial f is a field extension S>=T that sufficises f(a)=0 and S=T(a).)

Comment: Very good, I am not sure this is known to everyone.

Comment: I never heard of the term *rupture field* either. Wonder whether it is started - in spite of somebody making a WP.entry. Anyway, check your complex exponentials, $e^{\pi i}=-1$ and $e^{\pi i/2}=i$. Halve them angles, please :-)

Comment: The finite example is off in many ways. A) there does not exist a field with 21 elements. B) $x^4+1$ is not irreducible over $\Bbb{Z}_3$:
$$x^4+1=x^4+4=x^4+4x^2+4-4=(x^2+2)^2-2^2=\cdots.$$ I got a splitting field of nine elements. In fact, all the non-zero elements of the field $\Bbb{F}_9$ are zeros of $x^8-1$.

Answer (score 1):

For 1), indeed the factorisation into irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}$ is
$$
x^8-1=(x^4+1)(x^2+1)(x-1)(x+1).
$$
Now $x^{m}+1$ is irreducible if and only if $m$ is a power of $2$, via Eisenstein, see this duplicate:

[Prove $x^n+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ iff $n=2^k$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1621340/prove-xn1-is-irreducible-over-mathbbqx-iff-n-2k-for-k-in-mathbb)

This explains the hint.